# Change my Ubuntu DNS

Tags: 20.04, dns

How do I change the DNS on my Ubuntu, so that I can access blocked content?

Comment: DNS has nothing to do with blocked content. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: In my country, the Vimeo site is banned by the government, and I want to open it without having to use a VPN, because it makes the page load slow. How do I open the blocked site?

In Windows, I can change my DNS in Chrome using 1.1.1.1 DNS, so why is the option to change DNS not available in Chrome Ubuntu?

Comment: CAN NOT be done without a VPN.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the DNS server will not allow you to use blocked content.

However, connecting to a VPN will help you do so.

In order to connect to a VPN, first you must install a VPN serveice.

Refer this link to install PROTON vpn service on UBUNTU.  [PROTON VPN](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-setup/)

Comment: ...or if you don't want all that rigamore, just download and install PIA VPN.